# MongoDb (Mongoose) query docuemnt comparing two dates using $elemMatch and $and

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

In my database, I have a table with an object storing dates like this. I have a beginning date and hour (debut in french) and a ending date and hour (fin in french).

```
    "disposnibilites" :
     [    
...
      {
            "debut": {
                "$date": "2016-02-15T14:00:00.282Z"
            },
            "fin": {
                "$date": "2016-02-15T19:00:00.282Z"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "56d48f0bf94a4a642f4d2fc0"
            }
        },
...
       ]
```

My goal is to find all the document where the beginning time supplied is before the one in the DB and the end time is after the one in the DB. In Mongoose I run this query :

```
    { 'disponibilites' :
      {  $elemMatch :  {
          debut : { $lt : new Date("2016-02-15T15:00:00.282Z")},
          fin : { $gt : new Date("2016-02-15T18:00:00.282Z") }
    } 
} };
```

This send back all the documents available. Mongoose logs gives this informations :

```
Mongoose: document.find({ disponibilites: { '$elemMatch': { debut: { '$lt': new Date("Mon, 15 Feb 2016 19:00:00 GMT") }, fin: { '$gt': new Date("Mon, 15 Feb 2016 20:00:00 GMT") } } } }) { fields: undefined }
```

Now if I change the day to the 17th (where there are no entries in the DB for that day), it gives the same result :

```
    { 'disponibilites' :
      {  $elemMatch :  {
          debut : { $lt : new Date("2016-02-17T15:00:00.282Z")},
          fin : { $gt : new Date("2016-02-17T18:00:00.282Z") }
      } 
    }
```

Mongoose logs data :

```
Mongoose: document.find({ disponibilites: { '$elemMatch': { debut: { '$lt': new Date("Mon, 17 Feb 2016 19:00:00 GMT") }, fin: { '$gt': new Date("Mon, 17 Feb 2016 20:00:00 GMT") } } } }) { fields: undefined }
```

Eventually I will need to have something more complex like this :

```
{ 'disponibilites' :
   { $and : [
    {  $elemMatch :  {
        debut : { $lt : new Date("2016-02-17T15:00:00.282Z")},
        fin : { $gt : new Date("2016-02-17T18:00:00.282Z") }
    },
    {  $elemMatch :  {
        debut : { $lt : new Date("2016-02-18T15:00:00.282Z")},
        fin : { $gt : new Date("2016-02-18T18:00:00.282Z") }
    } 
   ]
   }
}
```

For now I want to understand why MongoDb can't compare dates properly ?

Comment: You are notably only showing "one" array entry. Chances are another array entry actually matches those conditions in the same document. "Queries" match "documents", not array elements. Adding a projection of `"disponibilites.$": 1` would show you which element is actually matching.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the *debut* and *fin* properties are objects with prop *$date*? If so than it should be more like `$elemMatch : { 'debut.$date' : { $lt:...`

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes I understand that, I entered the dates manually so I am sure there are no other arrays that are matching for that query.

Comment: @Molda MongoDB converted my date to an object with the ``$date``. When they send back the data, they remove the ``$date`` and only show the corresponding value. But I will check if querying ``$date`` helps!

Comment: What you need to understand is that without showing us data that agrees with your assertion it looks mainly like you might not understand as fully as you think. This is why when assert you are returning unexpected data, we would expect to see some evidence of this in your question. Without a reproducible case your question is unclear.